# /etc/sudoers problem, config works on machine B, but not on A

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

I've created a user noc and gave it a permission to run with sudo. I've added the following lines to the sudoers file.

```
Cmnd_Alias NOC = /etc/init.d/tomcat
noc ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOC
```

Problem is that when I try run `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat status` on machine A
it says: "noc is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported"

but I run the same command with same configuration on machine B, it works fine.

things I've checked:

- sudoers file permission is set to 0440
- all lines in sudoers file on    both machines are the exact same

I have CentOS 6.8 with latest updates installed.

Comment: I'm not sure if necessary, but did you log out then back in with noc?

Comment: Related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/665950/do-we-need-to-reboot-after-adding-an-user-to-sudoers.

Comment: have you run `sudo -l` as user noc, to make sure the sudo rule is truly there ?

Comment: yes user is truely there

Comment: sdiff the 2 files b/w the 2 servers and double check that they're not different.

Comment: When you added those lines to `/etc/sudoers` did you use `visudo` or did you just edit the file as you would edit any other file?

Comment: i edited the file normal way, i didnt use visudo